# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SPARK_RPC_SERVER_ADDRESS

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have install the hive 2.1.0 on spark,when I use hive client test the cluster.the hive throw the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SPARK_RPC_SERVER_ADDRESS
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.rpc.RpcConfiguration.<clinit>(RpcConfiguration.java:45)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver.<init>(RemoteDriver.java:134)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver.main(RemoteDriver.java:516)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.rpc.RpcServer.cancelClient(RpcServer.java:179)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.SparkClientImpl$3.run(SparkClientImpl.java:465)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How I config it?

Comment: This mostly seems to be version compatibility issue. Mention the versions of hadoop as well. Are you using hive on CDH or dependencies related to CDH?

Comment: thanks , it is the version problem.

Comment: @skystmm , May i know what was your spark version and what version did you try to fix it ?.

Comment: Can anyone please direct me towards the changes required on the hive and spark libraries or configurations?

Comment: Speaking for  myself, I ran into the problem with Hive 2.3.6 + Spark 2.3 + Hadoop 2.7.7.  When I moved back to HIve 2.2 with Spark 2.3 the error went away.

Comment: i'm having same problem i'm using spark 2..4.4 and hive 3.2.1  and hadoop 3.2.1